# How do you use math.random to generate random ints?

Tags: java, random

How do you use Math.random to generate random ints?

My code is:

```
int abc= (Math.random()*100);
System.out.println(abc);
```

All it prints out is 0, how can I fix this?

Comment: The code should really not print 0, it should not compile.

Comment: What version is that? The first line gives me "Type mismatch: cannot convert double to int" which is what I would expect.

Comment: @GworfHi For 0 - 100 use `int abc= (int)Math.random()*101;`

Comment: @God Casting `Math.random()` without multiplying 101 first means `abc` will always be 0. You gotta do `int abc = (int)(Math.random()*101);`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Cast abc to an integer.

```
(int)(Math.random()*100);
```

Comment: It should be noted this generates 0-99

Comment: just say add one : (int)(Math.random()*100+1));

Comment: @Russell That no longer generates 0 though.

Answer (score 22):

For your code to compile you need to cast the result to an int.

```
int abc = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
```

However, if you instead use the *java.util.Random* class it has built in method for you

```
Random random = new Random();
int abc = random.nextInt(100);
```

Answer (score 18):

As an alternative, if there's not a specific reason to use `Math.random()`, use [`Random.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-):

```
import java.util.Random;

Random rnd = new Random();
int abc = rnd.nextInt(100); // +1 if you want 1-100, otherwise will be 0-99.
```

Comment: (Explanations for down votes are generally appreciated, particularly when it's not clear that the OP wouldn't be better served with a more straight-forward solution.)

Comment: Why? Is one more random than the other?

Comment: @user3932000 Not that I'm aware of-it's just more clear.

Comment: Prefer this method, more cleaner than using Math.random

Answer (score 0):

```
int abc= (Math.random()*100);//  wrong
```

you wil get below error message

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int

```
int abc= (int) (Math.random()*100);// add "(int)" data type
```

,known as type casting

if the true result is

```
int abc= (int) (Math.random()*1)=0.027475
```

Then you will get output as "0" because it is a integer data type.

```
int abc= (int) (Math.random()*100)=0.02745
```

output:2   because (100*0.02745=2.7456...etc)

Comment: (It is generally helpful to format code as code, by indenting with four spaces or using the Ctrl-K shortcut.)

Answer (score 0):

you are importing `java.util` package. That's why its giving error. there is a `random()` in `java.util` package too. Please remove the import statement importing `java.util` package. then your program will use `random()` method for `java.lang` by default and then your program will work. remember to cast it i.e

```
int x = (int)(Math.random()*100);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this way for getting random number between 1 and 100 as:

```
SecureRandom src=new SecureRandom();
int random=1 + src.nextInt(100);
```

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow! Please have a look at [formatting code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) such that it is more readable

Comment: In general, you should only use SecureRandom when you need cryptographically strong random numbers, as it may block waiting for more entropy.

Answer (score -4):

```
double  i = 2+Math.random()*100;
int j = (int)i;
System.out.print(j);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add any value since identical answer was posted 3 years ago.

Comment: You're better off casting right away than storing it to a double of its own, unless you really really have to store `i`.