# Java insert random integers into binary search tree

Tags: java

Im trying to insert random integers into a binary search tree.

this is what ive tried

```
for(i = 0; i <= insertAmount; i++)
        {
            myTree.insert((int)Math.random()*1000000+1);
        }
```

I think im just inserting the same number. doesnt the + 1 change the value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610635/how-do-you-use-math-random-to-generate-random-ints

Comment: replace your **+1** with `i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be like this:-

```
(int)(Math.random()*100000)+1
```

The reason being your `(int)Math.random()` is giving `0` always and multiplication with `100000` has no effect. Hence, you're always getting `1` thanks to your `+1`.

Comment: you can either use `i` or `1`. Its your wish. You'll still get random number only.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the reply to your query, but you can consider Using [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class.

```
new Random().nextInt(1000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have this..

```
 for(i = 0; i <= insertAmount; i++)
    {
        myTree.insert((int)Math.random()*1000000)+i;
    }
```

> > You must replace the +1 with i.

hope it helps.

Comment: how do i get random numbers between a range? like if i want any random number between 1 and 1,000,000?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
Random rndm = new Random();
            int min =1;
            int max = 10;
            for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(rndm.nextInt(max - min + 1));
            }
```