# how to handle scroll up and scroll down with ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here I am uploading this link http://harvey.binghamton.edu/~rnaik1/myForm.html where you can see how my scroll up n down button is working in javascript but now I am working with Ajax request to a php script on the server to retrieve all of the data from the database table.
Here is the link for the work i have done:http://harvey.binghamton.edu/~rnaik1/myScrollform.html
Everything is working fine for me except scroll up and scroll down button.
Once you add 5 records in a list after entering 6th record it will show latest 5 records.

I want to make the scrollup and down button working for myScrollform.html in the same way as in myForm.html. Any help would be helpful to me and appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Scrolling Data Form</title>
        <script src="./jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="silver">
    <center><h1>My Scrolling Data Form</h1>
        <div id="scrollbar">
            <input type="button" name="up" id="scrollup" value="Scroll Up" >
            <input type="button" name="up" id="scrolldown" value="Scroll Down">
        </div>
        <div id="mydata" style="height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll">
            Currently we have no data
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="addformdata">
            <form name="addForm" >
                To add data to the list, fill in the form below and click on "Add"
                <br>
                <td><input type="text" id="name" name="namei" value=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="ssn" name="ssni" value="" ></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="date" name="birthi" value="" ></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="currency" name="xxxxi" value=""></td>
                <input type="button" name="add" value="Add" onclick="validateForm(); return false;">
            </form>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Arrays to store values 
    var name_Array=new Array(); 
    var ssn_Array=new Array(); 
    var date_Array=new Array(); 
    var currency_Array=new Array();
    var Index = 0;
    var first = 0;
    var last = 0;
    var scrolled = 0;
    var random_Array=new Array();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        fetchdata();
        $("#scrollup").on("click" ,function(){
            //            alert('hi');
            //            scrolled=scrolled+100;

            $("#mydata").animate({
                scrollTop:  0
            }, 800);
        });

        $("#scrolldown").on("click" ,function()
        {
            //            console.log($elem.height());
            $("#mydata").animate({
                scrollTop:  5000
            }, 800);
        });
    });

    function deleteRecord(id)
    {
        if(confirm('Are you Sure you Want to delete this record')){
            $.ajax({
                url:"insdel.php",
                type:'POST',
                data:  {
                    "action": "delete",
                    "id": id
                },

                success:function(data)
                {
                    fetchdata()
                    console.log('success');


                }
            });
        }
    }
    function  fetchdata()
    {
        //        var scrolled=0
        $.ajax({
            url:"insdel.php",
            type:'POST',
            data:  {
                "action": "fetch"
            },

            success:function(data)
            {    
                $("#mydata").html('')
                $("#mydata").html(data);
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
    }   
    function validateForm()
    {
        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var ssn = document.getElementById("ssn");
        var date = document.getElementById("date");
        var currency = document.getElementById("currency");
        var error = "";

        //Name validation
        if(name.value=="")
        {
            //Check for empty field
            name.focus();
            error = "Please Enter Name\n";
        }
        else
        {   //format specifier
            var letters = /^[a-zA-Z_ ]+$/;
            //Check for format validation
            if(!name.value.match(letters))
            {  
                name.focus();
                error = error + "Name contains only characters and spaces\nPlease Renter Name\n";
            }
        }

        //Date validation
        if(date.value=="")
        {
            //Check for empty field
            date.focus();
            error = error + "Please Enter Date\n";
        }
        else
        {   //format specifier
            var date_regex = /^((((0[13578])|([13578])|(1[02]))[\/](([1-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0[469])|([469])|(11))[\/](([1-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(30)))|((2|02)[\/](([1-9])|([0-2][0-9]))))[\/]\d{4}$|^\d{4}$/;
            //check for format validation
            if(!date.value.match(date_regex))
            {
                date.focus();
                error = error + "Date must be in mm/dd/yyyy format\nPlease Renter Date\n";
            }
        }

        //SSN validation
        if(ssn.value=="")
        {
            //check for empty field
            ssn.focus();
            error = error + "Please Enter SSN\n";
        }
        else
        {   
            //format specifier
            var numbers = /^\d{3}((-?)|\s)\d{2}((-?)|\s)\d{4}$/g;
            //check format validation
            if(!ssn.value.match(numbers))
            { 
                ssn.focus();
                error = error + "SSN must be in xxx-xx-xxxx format\nPlease Renter SSN\n";
            }
        }

        //Currency validation
        if(currency.value=="")
        {
            //check for empty field
            currency.focus();
            error = error + "Please Enter Currency\n";
        }
        else
        {
            //format specifier
            var pattern = /^(\$)\d+(\.\d{1,3})?$/g ;
            //check for format validation
            if(!currency.value.match(pattern))
            {
                currency.focus();
                error = error + "Currency must be in $xx.xxx format\nPlease Renter Currency\n"; 
            }
        }

        if(error)
        {
            alert(error);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var ssn = document.getElementById("ssn").value;
            var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
            var currency = document.getElementById("currency").value;
            console.log(name)
            adduser(name,ssn,date,currency);
            return true;
        }
    }


    function insertToList()
    {   
        // call a function to validate the fields
        var valid_function = validateForm();
        if(valid_function == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            //get the entered values from fields
            var name = document.getElementById("name");
            var ssn = document.getElementById("ssn");
            var date = document.getElementById("date");
            var currency = document.getElementById("currency");

            // push the values in the array
            name_Array.push(name.value);
            ssn_Array.push(ssn.value);
            date_Array.push(date.value);
            currency_Array.push(currency.value);

            // generate and push random number in the array to search the record in array and then delete that record.
            random_Array.push(Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1));// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610635/how-do-you-use-math-random-to-generate-random-ints

            //function to insert values to list
            InsertValues();

            // clear the fields after each add
            clearFields();

            alert("Record is successfully added to above list.");

            // set focus back on the name field
            name.focus();
        }
    }

    function clearFields()
    {
        document.getElementById("name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("ssn").value = "";
        document.getElementById("date").value = "";
        document.getElementById("currency").value = "";
    }

    // function to add to the list
    function InsertValues()
    {
        var temp = 1,temp1 = 1,index = 0,i=0;

        index = name_Array.length - 5;  

        for(i=0;i< name_Array.length;i++)
        {           
            // when only first 5 entries are added to the list
            if(name_Array.length>5)
            {
                // skip the first values so that only top 5 are shown in the list
                if(temp>s)
                {
                    if(temp1==5)
                    {
                        last = i;
                    }
                    else if(temp1==1)
                    {

                        first = i;
                        Index = i;
                    }
                    if(temp1<=5)
                    {
                        //initialise values of fields to the list
                        var str = "name" + temp1;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = name_Array[i];
                        str = "ssn" + temp1;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = ssn_Array[i];
                        str = "birth" + temp1;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = date_Array[i];
                        str = "xxxx" + temp1;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = currency_Array[i];
                        str = "random" + temp1;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = random_Array[i];
                    }
                    temp1++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var str = "name" + temp;
                document.getElementById(str).value = name_Array[i];
                str = "ssn" + temp;
                document.getElementById(str).value = ssn_Array[i];
                str = "birth" + temp;
                document.getElementById(str).value = date_Array[i];
                str = "xxxx" + temp;
                document.getElementById(str).value = currency_Array[i];
                str = "random" + temp;
                document.getElementById(str).value = random_Array[i];
            }   
            temp++;
        }
    }

    // Delete a record from the list
    function delete_a_Record(record)
    {
        var remove = 0,i=0,j=1;
        var name = document.getElementById("name" + record.value);
        var delRecord = document.getElementById("random" + record.value);
        if(name.value)
        {
            remove = 1;
        }
        // check for the existence of record
        if(remove == 1)
        {
            if(confirm("Click on 'OK' to delete the record\n"))
            {
                while(i < random_Array.length) 
                {               
                    if(delRecord.value==random_Array[i])
                    {               
                        // if yes then remove that record from list
                        name_Array.splice(i, 1);
                        ssn_Array.splice(i, 1);
                        date_Array.splice(i, 1);
                        currency_Array.splice(i, 1);
                        random_Array.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                    i++;
                }

                // make entire list empty
                while(j <= 5) 
                {   
                    var str = "name" + j;
                    document.getElementById(str).value = "";
                    str = "ssn" + j;
                    document.getElementById(str).value = "";
                    str = "birth" + j;
                    document.getElementById(str).value = "";
                    str = "xxxx" + j;
                    document.getElementById(str).value = "";
                    str = "random" + j;
                    document.getElementById(str).value = "";
                    j++;
                }
                //call this function again to insert values in the list
                InsertValues();
                record.checked = false; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Nothing to delete in this record.");
            record.checked = false;
        }
    }


    // function to perform scrollUp n scrollDown 
    function handleScrolling(type)
    {
        var j,k,temp2 = 1;
        // perform scroll only when there are more than 5 records in the list
        if(name_Array.length>5)
        {   // scroll up
            if(type==1)
            {   
                first--; // decrement the pointer to see upper records
                if(first>=0)
                {
                    for (j = first; j < name_Array.length; j++) // its showing top most record from jth position
                    {                               
                        var str = "name" + temp2;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = name_Array[j];
                        str = "ssn" + temp2;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = ssn_Array[j];
                        str = "birth" + temp2;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = date_Array[j];
                        str = "xxxx" + temp2;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = currency_Array[j];
                        str = "random" + temp2;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = random_Array[j];
                        temp2++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Top of the list is reached\n");
                    first++;// increment the pointer to see lower records
                }
            }
            else // scroll down
            {
                // increment the start point to see lower records if any
                first++;
                if(first<=Index)
                {
                    for (k = first; k < name_Array.length; k++) //its showing bottom most record in the list from kth position
                    {                               
                        var str = "name" + temp2;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = name_Array[k];
                        str = "ssn" + temp2;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = ssn_Array[k];
                        str = "birth" + temp2;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = date_Array[k];
                        str = "xxxx" + temp2;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = currency_Array[k];
                        str = "random" + temp2;
                        document.getElementById(str).value = random_Array[k];
                        temp2++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Bottom most record is reached\n");
                    first--;//decrement the pointer to see upper records if any
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Scrolling strikes for records more than 5\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
    function adduser(name,ssn,date,currency)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"insdel.php",
            type:'POST',
            data:  {
                "name": name,
                "ssn": ssn,
                "date": date,
                "currency": currency,
                "action": "add"
            },

            success:function(data){

                console.log('success');
                fetchdata();

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

//php file

```
<?php
extract($_POST);

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($con));
}
//mysql_select_db("ripal");
mysql_select_db("test");
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '" . $q . "'";
if ($action == 'add') {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO myform(name,ssn,date,income)VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($ssn) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($date) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($currency) . "')";
//  echo $sql;
    mysql_query($sql);
    echo mysql_insert_id();
} else if ($action == 'fetch') {
    $sql = "select * from myform";
//  echo $sql;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $str = '<form name="myForm">
                <table width="page">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center"></td>
                        <td align="center"></td>
                        <td align="center"></td>
                        <td align="center"></td>
                        <td align="center"></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>';
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $ssn = $row['ssn'];
            $date = $row['date'];
            $currency = $row['income'];
            $str.='<tr>
                        <td><input  type="radio" id="' . $id . '" name="del" onclick="deleteRecord(this.id);"></td>
                        <td><input readonly type="text" value="' . $name . '" id="name1" name="name"></td>
                        <td><input readonly type="text"  value="' . $ssn . '" id="ssn1" name="ssn"></td>
                        <td><input readonly type="text" value="' . $date . '" id="birth1" name="birth"></td>
                        <td><input readonly type="text" value="' . $currency . '" id="xxxx1" name="xxxx"><input type="hidden" name="random1" id="random1"></td>
                    </tr>';
        }
    }
    $str.='  <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" id="scrollCount" align="center" style="padding-top:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>';
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        echo 'No data in Our Database please add one or more';
    } else {
        echo $str;
    }
} else if ($action = 'delete') {
    $sql = "DELETE from myform WHERE id=$id";
//  echo $sql;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo $result;
}

mysql_close($con);
```