# Why does this loop keep going forever?

Tags: java, for-loop

Here is my code

here I made a loop which is supposed to break when the value of x becomes equal to the random number

```
public class Bark {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (double x = 0 ; x>-1 ; x++) {
        System.out.print(x + " ");
        if( x == Math.random()) {
            break;
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: why would you think this loop would stop? What are the chances of x being equal to Math.random?

Comment: It's not clear how you intended this to work. Express your requirements in words, and perhaps we can find a solution that works.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to improve your question.

Comment: "*The* random number" isn't strictly correct here because you're generating a new random number every single iteration, so there are actually lots of random numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You loop iterates from `0` to `Infinity` in increments of `1`, and `Math.random` can only equal a value from 0.0 to less than 1. If the `Math.random()` does not equal `0` on the first iteration, the loop will go forever.

Answer (score 1):

The for counter `x` starts at `0`, and increments every iteration (`x++`) and continues as long as `x` is `> -1`. `x` is greater than -1 when the loop starts and continues to increase, so is always `>-1` so continues forever.

The other check is `Math.random`, While Math.random does return a number between 0 and 1, it returning a `0` or `1` in the first iteration is very improbable.

Comment: `x` actually starts at `0`. The only chance for the loop to ever break is if `Math.random()` returns `0` on the first iteration. Unlikely to say the least. If that does not happen, `x` goes on to assume values `1, 2, 3, 4...` and the condition `x == Math.random()` will never hold.

Comment: Added the random part, missed the 0 vs 1. I have edited it in, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are generating a new random number each time.
To break, better generate random number once, within range, and then loop through.

Answer (score 0):

A few points here:

First, you're generating real numbers, not integers, but you're comparing it to integers. `x` will always be an integer, and `Math.random()` will generate a random real value between 0 and 1. (Note that the fact that `x` is technically of type `double` doesn't really help because you start at 0 and increment by 1 every time, so it'll always be an integer).

You should look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610635/how-do-you-use-math-random-to-generate-random-ints) to see how to generate only integers so that there's at least the possibility of it matching on each iteration.

Secondly, other answers have already pointed this out, but `Math.random()` will generate numbers between 0 and 1, meaning that the only times that this could possibly match are on the first or second iteration.

Third, this might be semantics, but referring to this as "*the* random number" isn't correct. You're generating a new random number each iteration, so you're actually generating lots of random numbers (not just one).